# Mesh and Bones Stretch After Rigging

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I'm new to blender and just started modeling. I made (what I think) is a cool little viking. Now I'm trying to rig him up, and I have aligned the bones and painted weights. But for some reason, when I rotate/move any limb, the entire bone and mesh stretch with it. I don't know what's causing this. Any solutions?

[image: Normal]

[image: Rotated & Stretched]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After redoing it, I realized I forgot to set the lower bones as a child of the spine. In short, I'm pretty sure the problem stemmed from having two root objects.

Comment: The problem is originally because the bone.head is scaled along Z.